# Sore legs on jogging daily

Tags: running, jogging, soreness

I have been jogging for almost more than couple of months now. I use to run on and of but I guess I was not too fit so could not run for more than 5 mins. This time I decided that I would not give up and would build a stamina good enough to run a 10k.

The problem I face is that I am not able to jog daily. I feel soreness in my legs (shin and calf muscles) if I try and I am not able to continue for more than 2-3 mins. But if I run on alternate days,I feel light soreness for the first few 100 meters and then it goes away.

I can run for about 25-27 mins and I run for about near 3 kilometers. I know I don't try to push too hard, I guess I do follow the 10% rule. I do stretch before and after jogging.

I am sure I am doing something wrong cause I have read that other people can run for 5-10 kilometers with ease daily.

The other problem I face is not being able to add much to stamina as I am progressing very slowly due to loss of breath. I try to breathe properly though.

I am a male, 68kg wt and 5'7''. I am from India. I have read people talking about getting proper shoes from some specialized store for running. I have not seen one around. So, I am not sure if I use right shoes. But I guess they are comfortable. Also, I run in a park with hard surface, not concrete, but bricks fitted together. I do have an option to go to another one with concrete surface.

So, my questions is, what should I do to be able to run daily as I really want to build stamina. In 2 months, 3km is a bit of disappointment. :(

Thanks for taking time to read this. It might be a duplicate question, but I could not find if the same issue was addressed in any other question.

Comment: I would suggest a couch to 5k program, or Galloway run/walk. And, if you don't have a store around, then I would suggest internet ordering for a pair of running shoes. Running in improper shoes can easily lead to injuries.

Comment: @JohnP - Thanks for the suggestion for the Galloway program. Not heard of it before, probably due to my lack of knowledge on the subject. But as far as shoes go, I am still a little skeptic about ordering them online as I see a lot of online stores tag all the shoes as running shoes. I don't want to buy very expensive shoes. I am not sure what would be the good shoes in the price I can afford. Also, as I mentioned, I am not even sure if I buy expensive ones, are they the right ones? Is there a site that can help select the right shoes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stick to what is working for you. If you cannot run everyday, but OK with running on alternate days, do that. Unless there is some deadline due to competition, there is no point in over-stressing yourself.

I am not a big runner myself and used be even worse, but I learned that persistence leads to good results and persistence is not possible if you do not enjoy the process. I could not run even 1km during my school years. I started running two years ago in the gym on the treadmill 3 times a week and went to 5k in about a year. Now I run 7-13k daily and taking a rest day after every 3 jogging days.

So, if alternate day running works for you now, do it. When you are ready, try switching to 2 days of running + 1 day of rest.

Comment: +1 for persistence and building up gradually. Distance running fitness comes almost entirely from long-term training.

Answer (score 0):

Static stretching where you hold a muscle in a elongated position is now discouraged pre-run, as it has been linked to injuries. A gradual warm-up is advised instead. 
1. Walk for three to five-minutes
2. jog lightly for 3 minutes
3. Gradually accelerate over the course of 60 to 100 meters, then gradually decelerate. (exact distance is not important and NEVER time, it is just a warm-up)
4. After each stride, walk around and shake out your legs for 1 to 2 minutes.
5. stride back in opposite direction
6. repeat 3 - 4 times

Answer (score -3):

Try a BCAA supplement. Drink before and after, and if you run longer than 45 minutes, during as well.

I also strongly recommend working your way up gradually, with run/walk intervals. My first training program was with a Jeff Galloway run/walk method. After a month or so I no longer needed to walk on long runs, and was able to modify my interval training by alternating between fast and slow running.

Comment: Do you have any science or studies that suggest BCAA helps with DOMS?